# Formulário com menu select não mostra os dados da API

Tags: javascript, react, rest, front-end, react-hooks

Estou fazendo um formulário de cadastro e nele tem um input do tipo select, que mostra todos os nomes (condominios) que é possível fazer esse cadastro.
Entretanto, ao abrir o modal e em seguida o campo de select, o dropdown está vazio, ele apenas é populado se eu troco de aba ou fecho o modal e abro novamente.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab';
import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Table from './devicesTable';
import { api } from '../../../services/api';
import { AuthContext } from '../../../contexts/auth';
import toastr from "toastr";
import "toastr/build/toastr.css";

const cond_data = []
const Register = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});
  const { role, id } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    api.post('/devices', {
      users_id: Number(values.location),
      serial_HR: values.serial,
      description: values.description
    }
    ).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.code === 401) {
        toastr.error(response.data.message)
      }
      else return toastr.success(response.data.message)
    })
  }

  const getCond = async () => {
    if (role === 'Admin' || role === 'Dev') {
      const response = await api.get('/show/location')
      const cond = response.data
      cond.map((item, index) => {
        cond_data.push([item.id, item.name])
        
      })
      
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getCond();
  }, []);
  

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Form.Select className="mb-3" aria-label="Default select example" onChange={(e) => setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, location: e.target.value }))}>
           <option hidden >Selecione o condomínio</option>
           
           {cond_data.map((item, index) => 
           {return <option value={item[0]}>{item[1]}</option>}
           )}
          </Form.Select>
          {/* <button onClick={getCond}>oi</button> */}
          <Form.Select className="mb-3" aria-label="Default select example" onChange={(e) => setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, user: e.target.value }))}>
            <option hidden>Selecione o usuário </option>
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
            <option>c</option>
          </Form.Select>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Control required placeholder="Serial" onChange={(e) => setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, serial: e.target.value }))} />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Control required placeholder="Descrição" onChange={(e) => setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, description: e.target.value }))} />
          </Form.Group>
        </Col>
        <Row className="justify-content-end">
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="col-sm-3 mt-2">
            Cadastrar
          </Button>
        </Row>
      </Row>
    </Form>
  )
};
```

Imagem - 1
[dropdown do select quando eu abro o modal pela primeira vez (vazio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMHdb.png)

Imagem - 2
[depois que eu faço alguma alteração na página e volto para o input select)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBaFy.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nessa situação, sempre que você tem uma lista e quer renderizar ela na tela, é bom botar ela em um useState, porque se você bota fora do componente, pode dar problema de renderização.

No seu caso, tentei melhorar um pouco do seu código também pra evitar alguns problemas:

1. Tirei o cond_data da linha 14
2. Coloquei um useState da lista conds

```
const [conds, setConds] = useState([]);
```

3. O seu getCond() estava populando a lista cond_data, e estava utilizando o método map da forma errada, já que o próprio map retorna uma lista, não precisando percorrer através dele pra adicionar cada item ao cond_data.
4. Acabei formatando o getCond() para ficar melhor de ler, sendo que quando a condição do if é verdadeira, o código para antes de tentar fazer a requisição.

```
const getCond = async () => {
    if (role !== 'Admin' && role !== 'Dev') return []

    const response = await api.get('/show/location')
    const cond = response.data.map(c => [c.id, c.name])
    return cond
}
```

5. Modifiquei o "html" para mostrar o conds

```
{conds.map((item) => { return <option value={item[0]}>{item[1]}</option> })}
```

6. Alterei o useEffect para popular o conds do seu UseState

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function populateConds() {
      const getResults = await getCond()
      setConds(getResults)
    }
    populateConds()
  }, []);
```

Dessa forma ficou assim, imagino que vá solucionar o problema:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab';
import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Table from './devicesTable';
import { api } from '../../../services/api';
import { AuthContext } from '../../../contexts/auth';
import toastr from "toastr";
import "toastr/build/toastr.css";

const Register = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});
  const [conds, setConds] = useState([]);
  const { role, id } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    api.post('/devices', {
      users_id: Number(values.location),
      serial_HR: values.serial,
      description: values.description
    }
    ).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.code === 401) {
        toastr.error(response.data.message)
      }
      else return toastr.success(response.data.message)
    })
  }

  const getCond = async () => {
    if (role !== 'Admin' && role !== 'Dev') return []

    const response = await api.get('/show/location')
    const cond = response.data.map(c => [c.id, c.name])
    return cond
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function populateConds() {
      const getResults = await getCond()
      setConds(getResults)
    }
    populateConds()
  }, []);


  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Form.Select className="mb-3" aria-label="Default select example" onChange={(e) => setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, location: e.target.value }))}>
            <option hidden >Selecione o condomínio</option>

            {conds.map((item) => { return <option value={item[0]}>{item[1]}</option> }
            )}
          </Form.Select>
          {/* <button onClick={getCond}>oi</button> */}
          <Form.Select className="mb-3" aria-label="Default select example" onChange={(e) => setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, user: e.target.value }))}>
            <option hidden>Selecione o usuário </option>
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
            <option>c</option>
          </Form.Select>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Control required placeholder="Serial" onChange={(e) => setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, serial: e.target.value }))} />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Control required placeholder="Descrição" onChange={(e) => setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, description: e.target.value }))} />
          </Form.Group>
        </Col>
        <Row className="justify-content-end">
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="col-sm-3 mt-2">
            Cadastrar
          </Button>
        </Row>
      </Row>
    </Form>
  )
};
```